# Make header in csv file a column using Talend

Tags: csv, talend

I have csv files with header as date. I want to add the header as a column to the rest of the columns I am getting.
What would be the best way to do it using Talend?
Here is the example data.

Jan 25, 2016
Account CampaignID  Campaign    Ad_group_ID

I would like that it looks like

Account CampaignID  Campaign    Ad_group_ID   Date

Where date has the header date.

I get the error that Parameter can't be null when I use two two tFileInputDelimited to split the header and rest.
I am using ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH")) in File name/Stream for both tFileInputDelimited.
What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Please post CSV document structure or sample records to better explain the question.

Comment: I just added an example

Comment: you can first read your file using tfileinputdelimited with limit=1 to read only date header and store it in global variable. Then read the file again using header=2 (to skip date header and other column header) and in tmap append the date to all rows coming out of tMap

Comment: The problem is that I am reading multiple files and when I have tFilelist connected with one tfileinputdelimited I get the error Parameter can't be null.

Comment: @JawadFazal Can you show us a picture of your "component" tab ?